# Validation in AngularJS is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form where i have two textfields added using the Bootstrap. Now i tried to add AngularJs validation for these two fields but not able to do it..Here is my Markup for userId textfield.

```
    <form role="form" name="Loginform" action="" method="post" class="registration-form">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="UserID">User ID</label>
    <input type="text" name="UserID" ng-model="user" placeholder="User ID..." class="form-first-name form-control" id="UserID" required>
    <span style="color:red" ng-show="Loginform.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid">
    <span ng-show="Loginform.user.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
    </span>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Please help me to resolve this ..Thanks..

Comment: `Loginform.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid` isn't even targeting the same form for both checks.

Comment: where is `name="user"`, where is input field for UserName ? you have name="UserID" and validation for `Loginform.user.$dirty`, I my understanding it should be `Loginform.UserID.$dirty`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please see I have updated code and made some correction 
http://jsfiddle.net/v7je78gq/

```
<span style="color:red" ng-show="Loginform.$dirty && Loginform.$invalid">
<span ng-show="Loginform.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
</span>
```

This is because of in you are check for property which is not exist in the form
hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

If you want to validate one or more input field, the best way is to create a controller and calling it.

```js
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.isInvalid = function(field){
    return $scope.myForm[field].$invalid && $scope.myForm[field].$dirty;
  };
  $scope.isValid = function(field){
    return $scope.myForm[field].$valid && $scope.myForm[field].$dirty;
  };
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
  <head lang="en">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  
  <body ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <form name="myForm" novalidate class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="control-group" ng-class="{error: isInvalid('name')}">
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" ng-model="user.name" required/>
        <span ng-show="!isValid('name')">Name is required</span>
      </div>
      
    </form>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

Hope it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

The name  of your input field is UserID not user.

```
ng-show="Loginform.UserID.$error.required"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input name did not correctly corresponded to the validation element

```
<form role="form" name="Loginform" action="" method="post" class="registration-form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="UserID">User ID</label>
                        <input type="text" name="UserID" ng-model="user" placeholder="User ID..." class="form-first-name form-control" id="UserID" required>
                        <span style="color:red" ng-show="Loginform.UserID.$touched && Loginform.UserID.$invalid">
                        <span ng-show="Loginform.UserID.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
                        </span>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: A code only answer is not very useful. Please [edit] the answer to explain the changes that have been made to the code and why they answer the question. Additionally, please explain how this answer differs from the other answers.